# How do I solve: No such file or directory?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to run:

```
python3 myfile.py > myfile.html
```

However *No such file or directory* always pops up even though I can see the file on my desktop?

Comment: You mußt give the absolute Path to python3. This way it looks in the current directory. `pwd` will show where you are.  Example ` python3 $HOME/python-skripte/Hallo-world.py` This is an absolut path. $HOME is a Variable that point to your home directory.   `pwd
/home/alex/python-skripte`   python3 Hallo-world.py  Now I use the relative path because I'm in the folder that contains the file.  `ls -l
insgesamt 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex    62 Mai  3  2011 Hallo-world.py`

Answer (score 3):

When you type

```
python3 myfile.py >myfile.html
```

in the terminal, it is assumed that the file `myfile.py` is already available in the current directory, and that `myfile.html` will be created in that same directory.

When you open up a new terminal window, the current directory will by default be your home directory, also known as `~` or `$HOME`.

However, you say that you can "see the file on your desktop", which likely means that the file is in fact in a desktop directory somewhere beneath your home directory, i.e. the file is not directly available in the home directory.

You then have a few possible alternatives.

1. Change directory in the terminal to where the Python script is actually located.  If the desktop directory is `~/Desktop`, then

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop
   ```

   will take you there. You may then run the `python3` command as above. The `myfile.html` file will be created in the `Desktop` directory.
2. Move the file into your home directory.  Provided that the file is located in the `~/Desktop` directory, you may

   ```
   mv ~/Desktop/myfile.py ~/
   ```

   which will move the file. You may then proceed with the `python3` command as above. The `myfile.html` will be created in the home directory.
3. Run the Python script with an complete path from the home directory:

   ```
   python3 ~/Desktop/myfile.py >myfile.html
   ```

   The `myfile.html` file will be created in the home directory.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are not in the correct directory. Try this:

```
cd ~/Desktop
python3 myfile.py > myfile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the current directory you are with:

```
$ pwd
```

If you are not on `$HOME/Desktop/`, navigate to it (using `cd ~/Desktop/`). 
After, run this command:

```
$ ls
```

This command will list all the files on the currently dir, check if you find `myfile.py`. If you prefer you can filter your search using grep, like this:

```
$ ls | grep 'myfile.py'
```

After you confirm that in the currently dir you are has a file named `myfile.py`, you will be able to run:

```
python3 myfile.py > myfile.html
```